# .htaccess 301 redirects in wordpress for select subfolders in a subfolder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Greetings and thank you in advance for your help!

I am trying to redirect certain subfolders from the "category" subfolder, but not all of them.  Only about 5 of them.

**Example:**

> http://domain.com/category/fish
>
> http://domain.com/category/lamb

Should redirect to

> http://domain.com/tasty/fish
>
> http://domain.com/tasty/lamb

But:

> http://domain.com/category/lead-paint

Should not.

What I've tried (in .htaccess):

```
 RewriteRule ^/category/fish http://example.com/tasty/fish [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^/category/lamb http://example.com/tasty/lamb [R=301,L]
```

I tried both before and after the Wordpress module. I also tried inserting inside the Wordpress module like so:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^/category/fish http://example.com/tasty/fish [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/category/lamb http://example.com/tasty/lamb [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Changes to .htaccess definately work.  Typos generate a 500 response, and I can block by IP address.  I'm not sure if Wordpress is overriding my redirects, or if I have a syntax error.

Thank you again.

Comment: You need to remove the leading slash just after `^` in the two rules. You also don't need to specify the full domain. Just `RewriteRule ^category/fish/?$ /tasty/fish [R=302,L]` will do. (Note the 302 - always test with a temporary redirect, then change to permanent when you're happy.)

Comment: @Mike Rocckett Mike, if you post this as answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the leading slash just after `^` in the two rules. You also don't need to specify the full domain. The following will do

```bash
RewriteRule ^category/fish/?$ /tasty/fish [R=302,L]
```

(Note the 302 - always test with a temporary redirect, then change to permanent when you're happy.)